# Combining text and strings

Tags: c#

I have the following file containing some information about an audio file.

```
Language = es-ES

Duration = 00:00:00.9100000

Unos amigos.
*

Language = es-ES

Duration = 00:00:03.5600000

Yo sé vamos a la fiesta en English with.
*

Language = en-US

Duration = 00:00:05.0200000

Hey, let us go to the party and Spanish. We say bye Marcella.
*

Language = es-ES

Duration = 00:00:02.2700000

Fiesta que yo use.
*

Language = es-ES

Duration = 00:00:00.8300000

La fiesta.
```

I want to combine the duration and every sentence together if it's the same language. I was thinking of splitting to an array of strings first using * as a delimiter but I don't know how to combine the duration or the sentences together, any help? I'm using C# btw. Is it better to create an object for each paragraph?

```
string[]subs=textFile.Split('*')
```

The wanted output:

```
Language = es-ES

Duration = 00:00:08.93

Unos amigos. Yo sé vamos a la fiesta en English with. Fiesta que yo use. La fiesta.

Language = en-US

Duration = 00:00:05.0200000

Hey, let us go to the party and Spanish. We say bye Marcella.
```

Comment: Hi. Please read the question and think if it's clearly understood to others to help you , also please paste text and not images. you should also provide an example of given input and desired output. help others to help you.

Comment: Yes, please replace the image with the text and I'll vote to re-open.

Comment: Ok, sry i'ts my first time here. Added text and wanted output

Comment: I've voted to re-open. You might want to check your output for `es-ES` as it doesn't look right.

Comment: I think the best approach to this problem would be to create a `class` containing `properties` Language, Duration and Text. Then I would make a `List` of said `class` based data from Split you've suggested. From there I'd loop on distinct values of Language property and add the values of instances with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var source = @"Language = es-ES

Duration = 00:00:00.9100000

Unos amigos.
*

Language = es-ES

Duration = 00:00:03.5600000

Yo sé vamos a la fiesta en English with.
*

Language = en-US

Duration = 00:00:05.0200000

Hey, let's go to the party and Spanish. We say bye Marcella.
*

Language = es-ES

Duration = 00:00:02.2700000

Fiesta que yo use.
*

Language = es-ES

Duration = 00:00:00.8300000

La fiesta.";

var results =
    from section in source.Split(new string[] { $"*{Environment.NewLine}" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    let parts = section.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    let language = parts[0].Split('=', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)[1]
    let duration = TimeSpan.Parse(parts[1].Split('=', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)[1])
    let text = parts[2]
    group new { duration, text } by language into languages
    select new
    {
        language = languages.Key,
        duration = languages.Select(x => x.duration).Aggregate((x, y) => x.Add(y)),
        text = String.Join(" ", languages.Select(x => x.text)),
    };
```

Given this source data I got this:

[image: results]

Comment: This is quite hard to read and I'm a Linq over-user myself

Comment: @NigelBess - Yes, agreed. I have tried to improve the readability.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you got that output, because I'm getting an IndexOutOfRangeException every time I try to print out the results

Comment: @Milad - I've added my exact source code. If you copy and paste from the HTML it should run perfectly. It did for me.

Comment: yeah i'm using the same source code, but i want to print out the results using:
foreach(var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine("language={0}, duration={1}, text={2}", result.language, result.duration, result.text);

but I'm getting an IndexOutOfRangeException. Sorry, I'm new to programing.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks for your help. The problem was with Environment.NewLine, I replaced it with "\r\n"

Comment: @Milad - You should not replace `Environment.NewLine` with `\r\n`. The purpose of `Environment.NewLine` is to make the code portable across OSes.

Comment: And the change from `Environment.NewLine` shouldn't have fixed a `IndexOutOfRangeException` error.

Comment: Hmmm that's odd, if i change  \r\n back to Environment.NewLine i get IndexOutOfRangeException immediately. It's like the split never happens and therefore there is no strings in the variable parts

Comment: @Milad - What environment are you running under? What values do you get when you call `Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray().Select(x => (int)x).ToArray()`?

Comment: I'm using vs code .net5 for macOS. I got the value 10 when i compiled the code above

Comment: @Milad - So your file has windows line endings and your OS has Linux line endings. You should change the code so that it's like this: `new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", Environment.NewLine }`. That way it will be robust for all circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like this. It is very messy and not good code,
but I am in a hurry so make out of it what you want.
It would be probably be best practice to make a class for each language.

```
    List<string> language = new List<string>();
    List<TimeSpan> duration = new List<TimeSpan>();
    List<string> text = new List<string>();

    void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"path\file.txt");
        string[] lines = file.Split('\n');

        for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            int pos = language.IndexOf(lines[i]);
            if(pos != -1)
            {
                i++;
                duration[pos].Add(TimeSpan.Parse(lines[i].Substring(10, 16)));
                i++;
                text[pos] += lines[i];
                i+=2;
            }else
            {
                language.Add(lines[i]);
                pos = language.IndexOf(lines[i]);
                i++;
                duration.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(lines[i].Substring(10, 16)));
                i++;
                text.Add(lines[i]);
                i += 2;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you test this? The OP provided the source data.

Comment: No as i said, i was in a hurry.. it was more just an idea